# Double-tap behaviour in android stock browser

Tags: javascript, android

I have a page here:

http://lonbus.net

That I have disabled double-tap zoom on mobile browsers via the inclusdion of the line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

This was done since when pressing buttons on the page it was easy to accidentally trigger a double-tap zoom.

This works. However, on the galaxy s2 phone (maybe others) double-tapping now seems to shift the whole page up or two the left, revealing white bars to the side of the page. Any thoughts as to why this happens...and if there is a way to capture the doubletap event completely and ignore it within the browser?

Research so-far suggests no

Answer (score 0):

For processing a double-tap event have a look at [this article](http://mscerts.programming4.us/programming/coding%20javascript%20for%20mobile%20browsers%20%28part%2010%29%20-%20event%20handling.aspx).

To cancel the event you can use the following code:

```
function eventHandler(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```